# How do I pass the text of a textbox from a pop-up window to the main form?

Tags: c#

My program is basically reading barcodes, but I want to allow users to enter barcode manually, so I created a pop up window for that. After entering the barcode, I want the pop up window to disappear and send data to the main form when ENTER is hit, but I have no clue how this data can be passed to the main form.

Comment: Add a public property to the pop up form; then the main form can access that property after the pop up is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is pretty straightforward, I'll show you with an example. You have two forms: Form1 mainForm and Form 2 subForm.

mainForm calls subForm as follows:

```
using (Form2 subForm = new Form2())
{
    if (subForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string my_text = subForm.TextToReturn;
        // Do stuff with my_text
    }
}
```

In SubForm you will have something like this declared in the class scope:

```
public string TextToReturn;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextToReturn = text_box.Text; 
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```